# Get Observable value inside .ts code

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-storage, angularfire2

I'm using Angularfire2 for uploading & downloading images. But after the `getDownloadURL()` is removed i'm stucked here.

```
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <input type="file" (change)="uploadFile($event)" />
    <div>{{ uploadPercent | async }}</div>
    <a [href]="downloadURL | async">{{ downloadURL | async }}</a>
 `
})
export class AppComponent {
  uploadPercent: Observable<number>;
  downloadURL: Observable<string>;
  constructor(private storage: AngularFireStorage) {}
  uploadFile(event) {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    const filePath = 'name-your-file-path-here';
    const fileRef = this.storage.ref(filePath);
    const task = this.storage.upload(filePath, file);

    // observe percentage changes
    this.uploadPercent = task.percentageChanges();
    // get notified when the download URL is available
    task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
        finalize(() => this.downloadURL = fileRef.getDownloadURL() )
     )
    .subscribe()
  }
}
```

I'm getting the `downloadURL` in the HTML page, but how to get inside the function?

Comment: subscribe for fileRef.getDownloadURL() since it returns an observable and you get the value in the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to subscribe to the this.downloadURL Observable to get the url string. The "async" pipe in HTML is basically doing the same thing. Subscribing und updating the value as soon as a value is emitted.

But you have to make sure that this.downloadRef is not not null. So in your code example, it must go into the finalize function.

```
 task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
    finalize(() => {
       this.downloadURL = fileRef.getDownloadURL();
       this.downloadURL.subscribe(url => console.log(url) );
    })
 )
```

But I am not sure, if finalize is the right function anyway. This code only works, if the snapshotChanges Observable completes or errors after the first emission. But I need more information about the background for a more detailed answer.

Comment: No problem. RxJS can be quite difficult in the beginning. But once you get the hang of it, you will love it ;)

Comment: Hello, i have the similar problem. How you pass this.downloadURL in reactiveForm after ?